# Show some data on customer emails related to Woocommerce product table plugin

Tags: plugins, woocommerce

In Woocommerce I am using Woocommerce product table plugin and I would like to show some data on customer order email notification, but I am stuck on getting this data.

The code I am using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'custom_email_after_order_table', 10, 4 );
function custom_email_after_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    $product_names = array();
    $product_test = array();

    // Loop thougth order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
        //$vendor_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $line_item->get_product_id());
       // $vendor = get_userdata( $vendor_id );
        $product = $item->get_product(); 
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get the product ID
        // Set each product name in an array
        $product_names[] = $item->get_name(); // Get the product NAME
        $prduct_test[]=$product->get_name();//testing
    }

    // Displaying
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Product names', 'woocommerce').':</strong> <br>'.implode( ', ', $product_names ).'</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Product test', 'woocommerce').':</strong> <br>'.implode( ', ', $prduct_test ).'</p>';
}
```

The data that I want:

[image: data I want]

Comment: There is many plugins for "Woocommerce product table"… which one are you using? Also the provided screenshot is not enough to get people to help you.

Comment: https://barn2.co.uk/wordpress-plugins/woocommerce-product-table/

Comment: As this is a non official commercial plugin, you should need to ask in the support pages from this plugin.